# Bootstrap Validator?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstraps frameworks to build a website and I would like to know if some kind of "validator" tool exist. (kind of like html 4 validator form W3C)

Comment: I mean the boostrap framework that we can find here http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: It's called Twitter-Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I could find: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-overview

Comment: Hello, no I didn't need a tool to check formulars but a tool witch can help me to detect syntax errors in bootstrap.

I found it, her name is bootlint, it's the official tool.  https://github.com/twbs/bootlint